# Why I am getting matrix dimension error in the line while calculating n?

Tags: matlab, function

Can you please tell me what's wrong with the following code?

```
    function [n]=calculate_n(p,delta)
    e = 1.6*power(10,-19);
    k = 1.38*power(10,-23);
    T = 298;

    co = 3.25*power(10,13)*e*power(10,4);

    er=12.5;
    eo=1.0;
    Nv=3*power(10,13);

    us = log((p*e)/sqrt(2*k*T*er*eo*Nv))*2*k*T;
    tmp = delta+(e*e*p)/co+us;
    n = 1/(exp((tmp))+1);
end
```

I am getting matrix dimension error while calculating n. Please help me.

Caller:

```
e = 1.6*power(10,-19);
x = logspace(13,18);
y=calculate_n(x,0.2*e);
semilogx(x,y,'-s');
grid on;
```

Comment: Are p or delta vectors? For p = 0.5 and delta = 2 it ran just fine for me...

Comment: I have added the caller code.

Comment: just replace `n = 1/(exp((tmp))+1);` with `n = 1./(exp(tmp)+1);` - But beware, `tmp`is so small for these values that `exp(tmp)` will always be 1. Also, there was a surplus bracket around tmp, you might wanna check if you put them correctly.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked.

Comment: Always glad to help. I put it in an answer so you can accept/close  it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace `n = 1/(exp((tmp))+1);` with `n = 1./(exp(tmp)+1);`. But beware, `tmp` is so small for these values that `exp(tmp)` will always be 1. Also, there is a surplus bracket around `tmp`, you might want to check if you put them correctly.

Edit:
The reason is that `A/B` tries to solve  the system of linear equations `A*x = B` for `x` which is not what you wanted. It threw an error because it requires both variables to have the same number of columns. `A./B` performs element-wise matrix division which is what you wanted. However, if `A` and `B` are singular `A/B = A./B`. See the [documentation](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/array-vs-matrix-operations.html) for more info.

Comment: Currently you provide a solution, but no explanation. IMHO, good answers should teach something. How about shortly explaining the difference between `/` and `./` and why `/` causes a matrix dimension error? (Disclaimer: I have nearly no idea about MATLAB.)

Comment: @honk You are right, not my best work. Gonna edit it - or is editing accepted answers very frowned upon?

Comment: If you won't completely change the solution, then I don't see any problem. Improving your posts is always welcome!